# Creating a generic retrieval method to return 1 record

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, ado.net

I am working through a code sample, and I just want to hear some opinions on the way that they have done things.  They use plain old ADO.NET.  They have a generic function called Read that brings back 1 record.  Here is the code:

```
public static T Read<T>(string storedProcedure, Func<IDataReader, T> make, object[] parms = null)
{
   using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
   {
      connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;

      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
      {
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         command.CommandText = storedProcedure;
         command.SetParameters(parms);

         connection.Open();

         T t = default(T);
         var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
         if (reader.Read())
            t = make(reader);

         return t;
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know why:

- They use `Func<IDataReader, T> make` as part of the method signature?  Is it efficient to do it like this?  Is there a better way/best practice to do this?
- I don't understand `T t = default(T);`?  Is it efficient to do it like this?  Is there a better way/best practice to do this?
- What does `t = make(reader);` do?  Is it efficient to do it like this?  Is there a better way/best practice to do this?

The calling function would look something like this:

```
public Customer GetCustomer(int customerId)
{
   // Other code here
   string storedProcedure = "MyStoredProcedure";
   object[] parameters = { "@CustomerId", customerId };
   return Db.Read(storedProcedure, Make, parameters);
}

private static Func<IDataReader, Customer> Make = reader =>
new Customer
{
   CustomerId = reader["CustomerId"].AsId(),
   Company = reader["CompanyName"].AsString(),
   City = reader["City"].AsString
};
```

I don't understand the `Func Make` part?  Can someone please explain to me what is happening here and if this is good practices.  Any changes would be appreciated, but please provide detailed sample code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delegate for the `make` (materialization) is pretty versatile and flexible, but IMO makes for a bit of unnecessary work in the vast majority of cases. In terms of what it *does* - they use the delegate as a callback to get the caller to specify how to read the record.

Note, since they don't expect the consumer to *change* record, they should probably be exposing `IDataRecord`, not `IDataReader` (any reader also implements record).

Note that if there are any error messages in the TDS stream *after* the first record, the approach shown won't see them - but that is an edge case. If you wanted to mitigate against that, you could read to the end of the TDS stream:

```
while(reader.NextResult()) {}
```

Personally, though, I'd just use dapper-dot-net here - avoids having to write that per-type code manually:

```
var cust = connection.Query<Customer>("MyStoredProcedure",
     new { CustomerId = customerId },
     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).Single();
```

this executes `MyStoredProcedure` as a sproc, passing in `@CustomerId` with the value from `customerId`, then applies a direct column<===>property/field match to create `Customer` records, then asserts that there is exactly one result - and returns it.

Answer (score 2):

> They use Func make as part of the method signature? Is it efficient to do it like this? Is there a better way/best practice to do this?

Due to the generic nature of the method `T` is unknown so they don't know how to map the reader back to `T` properties. So they leave this responsibility to the caller of the method. Actually this is efficient enough and it's good practice.

> I don't understand T t = default(T);? Is it efficient to do it like this? Is there a better way/best practice to do this?

Because `T` could be either value or reference type you cannot assign it to null. `default(T)` returns the default value for this type.In case of reference type this will be null. In case of a value type, for example integer, it will be 0.

> What does t = make(reader); do? Is it efficient to do it like this? Is there a better way/best practice to do this?

It invokes the delegate that is passed and assigns the result to `t`.